# Safe code or not? (Help needed)

Tags: php, sql

Is this code safe to use for my website? Without sql injections or hacking, yes or no? I dont want to be hacked etc.

```php
<?php

$db = new mysqli ("localhost", "-", "-", "-");

if($_GET['look'] && $_GET['username'])
{

    $username = $db->real_escape_string($_GET['username']);
    $look = $db->query("SELECT look FROM users WHERE username = '".$username."'")->fetch_assoc();
    echo $look['look'];
}

if($_GET['missie'] && $_GET['username'])
{
    $username = $db->real_escape_string($_GET['username']);
    $motto = $db->query("SELECT motto FROM users WHERE username = '".$username."'")->fetch_assoc();
    echo $motto['motto'];
}

if($_GET['while'] && $_GET['status'])
{
    $status = $db->real_escape_string($_GET['status']);
    $motto = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE motto = '".$status."'");
    while($lol = $motto->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $lol['username'] . '/';
    }
}

?>
```

And how can i improve it?

Comment: If you want to be safe, stop interpolating values directly into SQL statements (even escaped), and start using prepared statements with bind variables

Comment: I use this as a "api" for my another website to get the motto  and username etc. So i need to do that, right? @Mark Baker

Comment: If you access it from another website, then its publicly accessible

Comment: Yes, but people cant inject it with sql injection? Thats my question. @Mark Baker

Comment: You'd still be wrong; simply escaping arguments isn't enough: and that's why I'm saying you should switch to prepared statements with bind variables

Comment: If this code works as intended already, this question may be better off on [codereview.se]. Before you post your question over there, you should read up on the [rules over there](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I'm not a good at all with prepares statements. Maybe you can fix my code? @Mark Baker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the function description for mysql_real_escape_string, it states

> mysql_real_escape_string — Escapes special characters in a string for use in an SQL statement

so it will escape your parameters but I would not recommend relying wholly on that.

In future versions, php will no longer support mysql or mysqli and you will need to use PDO.  A good resource that I have used a number of times for my own projects is http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers.

PDO allows you to create prepared statements and will escape your parameters for you and protect yourself from sql injection. Here is an example of how you could do that using PDO:

```
$db = new \PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password');
$stmt = $db->prepare('
    SELECT *
    FROM `book` AS b
    WHERE b.genre = ?
');

$stmt->execute(array('fantasy')); // Will replace the ? with 'fantasy' and escape it
```

Comment: Thanks for the information! So, my code is safe? I'm filtering everything. @Jeff Burgin

Comment: Well according to the function definition, yes. But like some of the other comments say, prepared statements are safer and will be the standard moving forward.

Comment: I'm not a good at all with prepares statements. Maybe you can fix my code?  @Jeff Burgin

Comment: There's no plans to drop MySQLi from PHP

Comment: You may be right about that, but I know that MySQL has already been deprecated and they encourage all to use PDO. Look at the resource page I linked to, it will get you pointed in the right direction and has everything you need to switch to prepared statements.